# Java: How to make item use its own ArrayList<String> values in that items TextView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm getting ArrayList from intent. I insert that ArrayList, to every item I create into RecyclerView like this:

```
    mGameItemList = new ArrayList<>();

    /** Set selected names into the recyclerview **/
    for (int i = 0; i < ActivityNewGame.mCheckedBoxes.size(); i++) {
        mGameItemList.add(new GameItem(getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("PARNUMBERSINDIVIDUALLY"), ActivityNewGame.mCheckedBoxes.get(i), getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("PARNUMBERSINDIVIDUALLY").get(0), R.drawable.ic_minus, R.drawable.ic_plus, "TTL :", "0"));
    }
```

This is that GameItem:

```
public class GameItem {
    private ArrayList<String> mParNumbersIndividually;
    private String mText1, mText2, mText3, mText4;
    private int mImageMinus, mImagePlus;

    public GameItem(ArrayList<String> parNumbersIndividually, String text1, String text2, int imageMinus, int imagePlus, String text3, String text4) {
        mParNumbersIndividually = parNumbersIndividually;
        mText1 = text1;
        mText2 = text2;
        mImageMinus = imageMinus;
        mImagePlus = imagePlus;
        mText3 = text3;
        mText4 = text4;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllParNumbers() {
        return mParNumbersIndividually;
    }

    public void setAllParnumbers(int position, String newNumber) {
        mParNumbersIndividually.set(position, newNumber);
    }

    public String getText1() {
        return mText1;
    }

    public String getText2() {
        return mText2;
    }

    public void changeText2(String text) {
        mText2 = text;
    }

    public int getImageMinus() {
        return mImageMinus;
    }

    public int getImagePlus() {
        return mImagePlus;
    }

    public String getText3() {
        return mText3;
    }

    public String getText4() {
        return mText4;
    }

    public void changeText4(String text) {
        mText4 = text;
    }
}
```

The layout that this Activity uses:

[image]

The number of player throws (green background number) comes from that intended list. Its okay when I create hole 1, that it uses first numbers straight from that intended list, but when I go on, I have to make every item use its own ArrayList and manipulate those numbers with new numbers, so my question is, how I make my Items use their own ArrayLists for getting that green background number?

Comment: have a value in your model be that number specificly... and when you add/minus you set it as a new number. your question doesnt make sense tbh.

Comment: Player 1 has ArrayList, Player 2 has ArrayList, those green background numbers, has to come from their own lists.